# 2010 PPT Graphic, copied/pasted EMF to MSWord 2010, prints portrait not tabloid (both show in print preview)

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Creating graphic in 2010 PowerPoint, pasting as picture enhanced metafile into 2010 Word tabloid page -- shows in print preview -- will not print (tested on several printers)  (same prints fine on a portrait page) -- what is the issue?

Comment: Convert to PDF first and then print?